# Microsoft Graph OneDrive webUrl property not consistent

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The webUrl property of an Onedrive item differs on if the file can be opened Online or not.

As an example when I call `/v1.0/me/drive/root/children` I get items with

1. `https://domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user/_layouts/WopiFrame.aspx?source={{id}}&file={{filename}}`
2. `https://domain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Documents/Folder/filename.txt`

Why not using a consistent url here, as the Online Apps will also work with the second Url?

The second url can also be used by the client apps to open the document while the first url can't.

It's also hard to construct the second version of the link from the other item properties while the first link can be easily constructed.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the `webUrl` is to provide a `URL that displays the resource in the browser`. In the cases where a specialized experience can be provided (such as coediting office files in the web app) we'll return URLs specific to those scenarios, otherwise we'll return a generic URL and expect the browser to "do the right thing".

It is possible to always get URLs of the form of 2. by selecting the `webDavUrl` property when requesting the item.

See [this documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm#properties) for descriptions of these fields.

Comment: Thanks @Brad! Is webdavUrl always guaranteed to be returned for a given resource?

Comment: Yes, as long as you ask for it we should always be able to generate one